# How to Create Live connection between Amazon Redshift and Amazon RDS (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, optimization, redshift

I have a transaction table in MySQL which get updated almost every second. The table has about 20 million records and counting. I have been running queries directly on this table in my app development which has been having serious impact on performance especially when I have to call some queries using aggregate functions.

I want to connect the MYSQL to Amazon Redshift.

The problem is I want my connection to Redshift to be live. ie. Get Redshift updated with every insert in my tales in mysql.

1. How do I create the live connection to Amazon Redshift?
2. Is there any other way I can manage data without using Amazon Redshift?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a live connection from [MySQL to Redshift](https://www.alooma.com/integrations/mysql/redshift) you need to choose an appropriate database replication method. Among all existing methods, the [Change Data Capture (CDC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) is the most suitable for your case.

In this method, after a dump of the initial state of the database, the log of each database operation is continuously streamed and loaded into the data warehouse, and consolidated on a schedule (configurable) and the biggest advantage is that it enables near real-time replication.

A tool that I had a good experience with is Alooma, it can support near real time connection between Amazon Redshift and MySQL data base.